# How to install a custom component, while creating a new project or starting the server in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating an application on Angular2 where I am using few custom components like Angular2-tree component as well.

I am looking for the solution where while creating a project or  doing ng-serve, I can install all required components in single shot and I don't need to do npm install for each custom component and run a server.

Any lead will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Angular CLI specific.

Typically you just `npm install <your-packages>`. You can pass multiple NPM package names separated by a space ''.

If you want specific versions you can also add them to `package.json` and then run `npm install` without arguments to install them in one go.

That should be all.

If you have some components that don't have TypeScript definitions, you might need to install these manually. Let's worry about this only if you face it.

Comment: No problem! If this sounds like the answer to the question, I'd appreciate it if you can upvote it and/or mark it as correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the component to your dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-tree": "^1.0.0",    //Add this to your dependencies list, then npm install the whole project.
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
```

Some dependencies require extra configuration. It depends on what your adding. There arent really any super clever ways around your issue.